# Aws Aurora + Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core, amazon-aurora

I try to reduce the costs on my mobile app backend.

Today I use an ASP.NET Core Web API plugged to an SQL Server instance and I use Entity Framework Core. Everything in Azure Mobile App services + SQL Server.

I plan to migrate to a serverless approach and cloud paas db instance.

I chose AWS because moving to serverless lambda from an existing API Core project seems much simpler than with Azure Functions.

In my way to migrate I plan to do:

1. Move my Web API to a serverless app. I will use https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda way
2. I will use Aurora under MySql. Then I will not pay anymore the licenses for SQL Server. I will change in my backend the connection string in my Entity Framework Core and do some minor changes to move from SQL Server provider to MySQL. And I will purchase for instance reserved 1 year.

Based on this I think I will reduce my costs (move from SQL Server to aurora MySQL), gain in scalability and performance with serverless functions.

Is it a good way?

Finally in my Web API .NET Core project, I use Swagger UI and Hangfire UI.
May I use it if I move my project as serverless?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great plan, a couple of things to consider in your plan that would improve it are below.

Will the Aurora DB always be required to be running? If not you can use [Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) to use it only when you need to be using it (primarily for writes), look at using [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) for any caching of common queries to reduce the number of calls to your cluster if you can avoid it. Also look at other [managed database services](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/) that might be appropriate for your use case.

For calling the API from the document you've shared it specified API Gateway as the caller of the API, you can enhance this for authentication by looking at [custom authorisers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) which would take the authorization code out of your Lambda and instead make API Gateway responsible for authentication/authorization.

Comment: @bhargav Rao why did you delete my answer?

Comment: @dalton5 you'd be better trying to reach out for a private message through chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ :)

Comment: Regarding your question, you would use CloudFront combined with S3 (and API Gateway). CloudFront supports multiple origins (sources). You can define that particular path patterns go to different sources. S3 would contain your documentation with another path for your API: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/

Comment: Quick question on Aurora Serverless. How is the performance for a mobile app backend compared to aurora? If I choose this solution will I reduce the costs compared to the Aurora?

Comment: It depends on your use case, it can scale engine size to meet demand and can temporarily disable if no network traffic in (you can tweak this). If you have a fairly constant stream though it won’t be effective

Comment: Ok I setup mysql in mycode and created a free tier mysql db. Now I will setup lambda. Just a quick question I truied some simulations of auraora with mysql support. It seems very expensive. Do you think shared hosting of mysql db or vps should be better and cheaper? Thanks

Comment: Aurora can be expensive at first, as you move through higher performance demands it generally becomes more affordable and delivers more for the money. You can of course use RDS MySQL or MariaDB instead if you want a managed MySQL for a bit cheaper. I would recommend RDS if you do not want to to manage patching  and maintenance of your DB